# take hex character, insert random character after it, take second hex character and insert another random character

Tags: java

I'm very new to programming, and this one has me scratching my head.

Well, more like banging my head.

The idea of this program is to take an input, convert it to ASCII, then to  hex, then create a random character, insert it after the first hex character, take the second hex character, and then insert another random character after the second hex character.

such like:  randChar1 + 1st char of hexString + randChar2 + 2nd char of hexString

for example,

the hex code for "asdf" is 61736466. what i need to do is seperate the 61 from the group, insert  random characters i.e. "R,u" in such a way that it displays "6R1u" where the first and 3rd characters is one single hex code. I'm not quite sure how to do that since strings are immutable, and I'm seriously so stuck its ridiculous. I've searched hundreds of forums, literally, and have yet to come accross  one as specific as this question is.

aside from the inserting random characters, what i need to do is  take the new string consisting of 4 characters, and iterate through each hex code, which i also have no idea how to do.

i.e.

take 61, add random characters at index 1 and 3, take 73, repeat adding characters, and do this for the length of the word.

i am so absolutely stumped  on how to do this, it's incredibly  frustrating sitting here trying to figure something like this out when you havent the slightest clue.

I'm sorry if i'm not wording this properly or making this sound confusing.

This is essentially the pseudocode given to  us by our professor, however i have made many modifications, so none of this code is final and half of it is still pseudocode.

again, apologies if this is terrible wording and format, it's my first post. I'm really just concerned with getting the encryption  working, I'm not worried  about decryption at this point.

it  would just be wonderful if someone could point me in the right direction,  to where i could write code that enables the program to achieve something to this degree:

(randChar1 + 1st char of hexString + randChar2 + 2nd char of hexString): gives me a 4 character string consisting of only one hex code. break each double digit hex and in between add random characters, and iterate through each hex code, adding random letters in the same fashion at indexes 2 and 4, until all hex code has been converted to a 4 character "encrypted" string

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project    Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
  */
package encryptionprogram;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Elliott Cade
 */
public class EncryptionProgram 
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String plainText, encryptedText, decryptedText, asciiValue, ASCII;

    System.out.print("Enter message: ");
    plainText = sc.nextLine();                //takes user input
    asciiValue= plainText;

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Encrypted message");
    encryptedText = EncryptCharacter(asciiValue);
    System.out.println(encryptedText);              //disregard
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Decrypted message:");
    decryptedText = DecryptMessage(encryptedText);   //disregard
    System.out.println(decryptedText);
    ASCII = EncryptCharacter(asciiValue);
    }

     public static String EncryptMessage(String plainText)
    {

encryptedMsg = 

{                                                          //disregard all


}
    {
encryptedChar = EncryptCharacter(plainText.charAt(i));
encryptedMsg = encryptedMsg + encryptedChar;    
    }
Return encryptedMsg
}



public static String DecryptMessage(String encryptedText)
{    String decryptedMsg,encryptedLetter;

        decryptedMsg = “”
for each group of 4 characters character in encryptedText
{
    encryptedLetter = encryptedText.substring 4 characters
    decryptedChar = DecryptCharacter(encryptedLetter);    
encryptedMsg = encryptedMsg + decryptedChar;    
}
return decryptedMsg;

}

private static String EncryptCharacter(String asciiValue)
{   

char[] chars = asciiValue.toCharArray();
StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder();          
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)             //takes input and        converts  it to hex format
    hex.append(Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i]));
    System.out.println();
{

}
return hex.toString();


}     

public static char DecryptCharacter(String encryptedCharacter)
{
// You need to implement this function



decryptedChar = char1 + char3
ASCIICode = convert hexadecimal decryptedChar to an ASCII decimal code
decryptedChar = convert ASCII code to a character
return decryptedChar;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `StringBuilder`. Then

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char a = (char) rand.nextInt(range);
    sb.append(str.charAt(i));
    sb.append(a);
}
return sb.toString();
```

change `rand.nextInt()` to fit your range of characters you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding! how exactly would i incorporate this into my code...? I'm sorry if these are horribly tasteless quesitons, but  i am the beginner of beginners.